# emacs: remove __PYTHON_EL_eval message

Tags: emacs

Can Someone help me to remove the " __PYTHON_EL_eval..." message when I use run-python in Emacs?

```
name = "Jack"
print(f"Hello {name}")
```

Inferior Python Output:

```
__PYTHON_EL_eval("name = \"Jack\"\nprint(f\"Hello {name}\")", "/Users/Shared/ej1.py") Hello Jack
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack, but it worked for me:

```lisp
(defun python-comint-filter (output)
  (let* ((regexp "^.*__PYTHON_EL_\\(.*\\)\\(.*\\)[[:space:]]*$")
         (lines (split-string output "\n"))
         (filtered-lines (remove-if (lambda (line)
                                      (or (string-match-p regexp line)
                                          (string-match-p "^\\s-*$" line))) 
                                    lines)))

    (if (equal (length lines) (length filtered-lines))
        output
      (mapconcat 'identity filtered-lines "\n"))))
```

and

```
(add-hook 'comint-preoutput-filter-functions 'python-comint-filter)
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider adding the following command to your init file, it did the job for me

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython"
      python-shell-interpreter-args "-i --simple-prompt")
```

For more info see the [elpy-documentation](https://elpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ide.html#interactive-python)

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use `ipython` for your shell, or if you don't want to use elpy just for `elpy-shell-send-region` you can try to following filter:

```lisp
(defun python-comint-filter (output)
  "Filter out '__PYTHON_EL_' when sending region to inferior Python shell."
  (let ((clean-output (replace-regexp-in-string "__PYTHON_EL_eval(\".*?[\\]n\\(\\w+.*\\)\"\,.*" "\\1\n'" output)))
    (replace-regexp-in-string "\\\\." #'python-comint-replace-escape clean-output)))

(defun python-comint-replace-escape (match)
  (let ((char (substring match 1)))
    (pcase char
      ("n" "\n")
      ("r" "\r")
      ("t" "\t")
      ("b" "\b")
      ("f" "\f")
      ("\"" "\"")
      ("'" "'")
      ("\\" "\\"))))

(add-hook 'comint-preoutput-filter-functions #'python-comint-filter)
```

The result:

[Adjusted Python shell input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYB8y.png)

Note that this only works properly with a `python` shell - I can't get it to work with `ipython`. However, this solution is sufficient for me, as I have no use for the numbered "cells" for my use case.

Comment: You should have the second function ```dn/python-comint-replace-escape```, the error comes from the previous one.

Comment: Thanks for noticing! Although this was an error from copying my config over to StackOverflow: the function still does not work for `ipython`. I think its process produces the output in a different way. I corrected my original post for future readers though.